# Google Apps Script code to rename and move files

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-apps

I'm using the below code to on a form that begins with 3 short answer items followed by several file uploads. The code below is intended to rename the two file uploads and move them to a specified folder. I've been able to save the code as a script and run the form submit trigger, but it is not working when I upload files. Is there anything clearly wrong with it?

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  //get the response
  const formResponse = e.response;

  //get an array with all the responses values 
  //(values in the array are ordered as the form, so the first item is the customer code, second item is registration drive file id...)
  const parentFolder = '1gLqUT-fHvB2wLOfF2XA0RCVC7gvJ9AeXd';
  const itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  //get serial numbers
  const subjectID = itemResponses[0].getResponse();  
  const podSN = itemResponses[1].getResponse();  
  const patchSN = itemResponses[2].getResponse();   
  var id;
  var questionName;

  //get the id of each file uploaded (positions 3, 4, and 5) and the relative question name, and change the files name
  for(var i = 3; i < 5; i++){
    id = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    questionName = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle();
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).setName(subjectID + "_" + podSN + "_" + patchSN + "_" + questionName);
    DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(parentFolder);
  }
}
```

Comment: Check [My Executions](https://script.google.com/home/executions) for any failed executions. The logs within help reveal why the script is failing.

Comment: @doubleunary it says: Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at onFormSubmit(test:4:26)

Comment: You say that you `run the form submit trigger`.  How are you doing that?

Comment: @ESIRMITS - How did you setup your trigger? Could you include a screenshot of it?

Comment: Do not run the code in the script editor. If you do, the event parameter `e` is not populated, causing the error you mention. The code is designed to run when the [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) fires.

Answer (score 0):

Correct your code

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).moveTo(parentFolder);
```

as following

```
DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolder));
```

For trigger creating use the following function

```
function setOnSubmitTrigger(fname){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(fname || 'onFormSubmit')
      .forForm( FormApp.getActiveForm())
      .onFormSubmit()
      .create();
}
```

If you are not familiar with Apps Script, then you can use ready-made solutions from the [Google Workspace Marketplace](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/search/Form%20Uploads).